# .NET Maui TapGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am currently working on a Maui project in .NET 8 but I have troubles with the TapGestureRecognizer I use in a CollectionView.

Snippet from my XAML:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodel:SearchLoadingListVM />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<Page.Behaviors>
    <ctk:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="#005ea8" StatusBarStyle="LightContent" />
</Page.Behaviors>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="60*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                         Grid.RowSpan="2"
                         Margin="0,30,0,0">

        <Image Source="deliveryboximage.png"
               HeightRequest="150" />

        <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Entry BackgroundColor="White"
                   HeightRequest="40"
                   WidthRequest="280"
                   MaxLength="10"
                   TextTransform="Uppercase"
                   Placeholder="Auftragsnummer"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                   Margin="0,0,-80,0"
                   IsEnabled="{Binding IsEntryEnabled}"
                   Text="{Binding EntryTextValue}"
                   TextColor="Black" />


            <ImageButton Source="barcode_scanner.svg"
                         Scale="0.7"
                         Margin="0,0,0,7"
                         Command="{Binding ScanBarCodeCommand}" />

            <ImageButton Source="search.svg"
                         Scale="0.7"
                         Margin="-5,0,0,7"
                         Command="{Binding ExecuteSearchCommand}" />


        </HorizontalStackLayout>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
    <ScrollView IsEnabled="{Binding IsScrollViewEnabled}"
                Grid.Row="1">
        <CollectionView
            ItemsSource="{Binding LoadingListCollection}"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <Grid Padding="2">
                        <Frame BorderColor="LightGray">
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:SearchLoadingListVM}}, Path=ItemTapedCommand}"
                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding .}"
                                       FontSize="22"
                                       TextColor="Black" />

                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

The generated code by the MVVM Community Toolkit:

```
partial class SearchLoadingListVM
{
    /// <summary>The backing field for <see cref="ItemTapedCommand"/>.</summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.RelayCommandGenerator", "8.2.0.0")]
    private global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.AsyncRelayCommand<string>? itemTapedCommand;
    /// <summary>Gets an <see cref="global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.IAsyncRelayCommand{T}"/> instance wrapping <see cref="ItemTaped"/>.</summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.RelayCommandGenerator", "8.2.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.IAsyncRelayCommand<string> ItemTapedCommand => itemTapedCommand ??= new global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.AsyncRelayCommand<string>(new global::System.Func<string, global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task>(ItemTaped));
}
```

The VM (ItemTaped() should be called):

```
public partial class SearchLoadingListVM : ObservableObject

{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<string> loadingListCollection;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string entryTextValue;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isEntryEnabled = true;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isScrollViewEnabled;

    private WebService.WebService webService;

    public SearchLoadingListVM()
    {
        CheckPermission();

        loadingListCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        webService = new WebService.WebService();
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public async void ScanBarCode()
    {
        IsEntryEnabled = false;
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync( nameof( CodeScannerView ) );
        IsEntryEnabled = true;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public async void ExecuteSearch()
    {
        if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( EntryTextValue ) )
        {
            IsEntryEnabled = false;
            await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync( new BusyIndicationModal() );
            LoadingListCollection = await webService.GetLoadingListsAsync( EntryTextValue );
            if( LoadingListCollection.Count == 0 )
            {
                
            }

            await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            IsEntryEnabled = true;
        }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task ItemTaped( string item )
    {
        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync( new CameraView() );
    }

    async Task CheckPermission()
    {
        PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>();

        if( status != PermissionStatus.Granted )
        {
            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
        }
    }
```

I did copy the XAML code from a video by James Montemagno and the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74163911/navigation-in-net-maui-doesnt-work-tapgesturerecognizer) question.
Interestingly it did work before but after the last Visual Studio update my whole solution broke and even after restoring some of the before used code it doenst work.
When I set Break Points at the two methods seen above, the studio doenst broke at any of them. There are also some other RelayCommands implemented which all work fine, so I guess the problem is my XAML?

Does anybody know if I missed out anything or why it doenst work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should start by removing "Frame" and replacing it with "Border".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue.

That because you set `<ScrollView IsEnabled="{Binding IsScrollViewEnabled}"`. The default value of `IsScrollViewEnabled` is false. You disable the parent control (ScrollView), the child control is also disabled.

You may also find the text is gray. If you set
`IsScrollViewEnabled=true`. Then the label textcolor will be black and the command will be fired.

Please let me know if you have any questions.